# Past simple vs past perfect mc

Tags: past-perfect

1 I thought you like me

2 I thought you had liked me

Is there any difference between these tenses. In my opinion only second one is correct because first was " liking" then " understanding". Am I worng and if so could you give me the precise meaning of both? Could you also explain the difference between

1 I thought you were right

2 I thought you had been right

Here I also think that only second one is correct.

Comment: I think you mean "The precise meaning" not the "precious meaning"  (autocorrect?)

Answer (score 1):

"I thought you like me" does sound odd.  But there is no need for the past perfect.  "I thought you liked me" is correct. When you say "I thought" you normally imply that you now think differently.

There's no need for past perfect, and it shouldn't be used for this stative verb.

"I thought you were right" is the normal expression.  It means that, in the past my belief was "you are right", (but now my belief is "you are wrong"). "I thought you had been right" is less common, it would mean "In the past, my belief was "you have been right".  But believing that someone has been right is rather an odd thing to believe.

So in these examples, the simple past "liked me" or "were right" are the correct forms to use.  With a more dynamic verb you might use past perfect.  "I thought you'd climbed Mt Fuji."

Comment: How can I know when to use past perfect for instance: I didn't came becasue I broke my leg is wrong I need past perfect.  What about I heard something moved or had moved? Do we have here two different meanings?

Comment: The only mistake is the form "came"... if you say "I didn't come because I broke my leg" it is correct English.  You don't need past perfect.

Comment: James K. Do we ever have to use past perfect or it's always changeable with past simple?

Comment: I would say "I didn't come because I had broken my leg", because the injury presumably happened before the 'not coming'. An American would be more likely to use the past simple.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in both cases. 'Liking someone' and 'being right' are not single actions but ongoing situations. If the person no longer likes you or is no longer right, we would use a form of words which make it clear that the situation has changed.

> I thought you used to like me.

or

> I used to think you liked me.
>
> I used to think you were right.

Answer (score 0):

1 I thought you like me. [BUZZER]

Present tense: I think you like me.

2 I thought you had liked me [OKAY]

Correction for 1): I thought you liked me. [but apparently you don't].

Clarification for 2): I thought you had liked me [for example: before the accident occurred.]

The past perfect is **generally preceded** by a simple past, in fact or implied. In your example it is implied.

- I thought you were right. [OKAY]
- I thought you had been right [before I realized you weren't].
  OR
- I originally thought you had been right. [before x in the simple past, for example]